# Can not convert LPTSTR to std::string in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Just like the title says, I can not convert LPTSTR to std::string in release mode. In other words, when I'm doing this:

```
LPTSTR lpt;
std::string str = lpt;
```

This only works when I'm in debug mode. The compiler says that no matching constructor could be found. Did I forget to include something?

Comment: Perhaps release mode has `UNICODE` defined. Just use `PWSTR`, or, better yet, `std::wstring` from the beginning.

Comment: Make sure that `UNICODE` is defined for both builds. Always use wide strings for Windows applications. `std::wstring` is a good choice for all code you write, but the Windows APIs are not going to use it because they are C APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this function

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string LPTSTRToString(LPTSTR Input)
{
    string Output;
    for (int i=0;i<((wstring)Input).length();i++)
        Output+=Input[i];
    return Output;
}
```

Comment: -1 That's a very very bad way to convert from UTF-16 to ANSI. Not that there are many great ways, but this is as bad as it gets.

Comment: It's also a bad way to formulate an answer.

Comment: Well... that worked for me.
Can you please tell me what is a better way to convert from LPTSTR to std::string? Currently I'm not finding another way.